# Python - google drive authentication using email and password

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm creating a simple python 2.7 application that uploads files to Google drive.

I've used [PyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) examples and they work quite well.

But in all the examples they all require the client to get their authentication secret key from their Google account and add it to the client_secrets file.

Is there a way to authenticate to Google drive in Python using Client email and password credentials?

<del>I know this is possible using [google spreadsheet](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-google-spreadsheet-from-python/)</del> (API unavailable)

Comment: The way you're supposed to do it is to ask the user to give their username and password to Google, and get back the credentials. Is there a reason you _don't_ want to do that?

Comment: @filow the article you cited is dated back in 2009. I don't think the API is still available: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=1

Comment: @albarnert That's the way I expected it to work. Although I can't get the URL redirection to the page asking for credentials, authorizing the application, without the client secret key. so far